# how can I get the expand level in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using AgGrid React with Row Grouping and SSRM.
I want to update the header in the Group column that AG Grid creates
For example let's say my (4) columns are named A B C & D.
I would like the header to display A when nothing is expanded
A->B when first level is expanded and so on.
The tricky parts:

- when the group is collapsed from the first level, because when you reopen it, it remembers the other nested levels opened (I want to keep this feature)
- when more groups are expanded & collapsed

[image: image of ag grid created group column]

Looking for a solution within ag-grid, not React state.
Any help will be appreciated

Will try to create a plunker later. (sorry for no code example)

I did not find any help in their docs on this topic.
I've tried making use of `onRowGroupOpened`, `api.getGridOption('autoGroupColumnDef')` but except the current level, which is kind of wrong because it is related to the triggered level event (expand/collapse)

What I would like to know is if it is possible to get the "real" level at update time.
So when I open first level it would be 1
When I open second level it would be 2, and so on.
Then if I collapse directly to 0, it would be 0.
Then if I expand back to 1, it would be actually 2, because I never collapsed that.

Answer (score 0):

To have the header contain dynamic text, I would recommend using a custom Header Component. You set a Header Component for the Auto Group Column using autoGroupColumnDef.headerComponent, creating a Header Component is covered here: https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-headers/

Secondly to register for group open/closed, listen for the grid event rowGroupOpened

Comment: thank you for the reply. nice to see the author responding <3
let's say I have a row grouping over 4 columns A,B,C,D
if I expand the first item in each column, the level value returned is
1 after  I expand A
2 after  I expand B
3 after  I expand C
4 after  I expand D
then, if I collapse directly from A -> I get level 0
then in I expand from the same A -> I get level 1 - Since the grid remembers the other expanded columns - should it not be 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

found what I needed - it was in the grid state
api.getState().rowGroupExpansion?.expandedRowGroupIds
this lets me know the current expanded rows, and their "depths"